# CoreAudio: Crackling after Mac woke from sleep

Tags: macos, core-audio

I need help debugging an issue, where an application that uses CoreAudio to mix several input sources into an output screen, experiences crackling in the output stream, but only after the Mac has woken from sleep.

The app was running fine before the Mac went to sleep, and restarting the app fixes the problem.

The application uses a couple of threads to do it's thing, which makes me assume that resource limits are altered by the system for the app, or some buffers used by CoreAudio have changed in size.

Any ideas how to debug that issue?

Comment: My first thought is that (internal Core Audio) buffers might be empty (enough) to produce the crackling. That is, producer side stops, but consumer side continues. Do you tear down the audio processing at the moment the Mac goed to sleep?

Comment: No, the mixer is left enabled during sleep/wake cycles. Do you suggest disabling audio processing during sleep, and setting up anew when the system returns from sleep?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Although depending on the way you do the audio processing. Could you provide more details on what frameworks or api calls you use?

Comment: I'm not the original author, but it seems the hard work is done by an CoreAudio Multi Channel Mixer. kAudioUnitType_Mixer/kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer